# How can I load my UITableView with a list of saved files in my documents directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

How can I load my UITableView with a list of saved files in my documents directory? I just need a small example or a simple online tutorial as I've been pulling my hair out. All the files are saved to the iOS document directory and all I need to do is list them in my UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *filePathsArray;

- (void)setUpTheFileNamesToBeListed
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [filePathsArray count];   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    //Insert this line to add the file name to the list
    cell.textLabel.text = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. How can I now open the file in a UIWebView when the row is tapped?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of the documents directory using

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

You will get the list of files in it using

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
```

This array will contain directories as well as files. Enumerate through dirContents and check if it is a file using

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path
```

If the file does not exist, either filter that out from the dirContents or else create a new array with paths of only the files that do exist and use that as a datasource for the table view.

Comment: Again, really helpful - thanks! How can I now open the file in a UIWebView when the row is tapped?

Answer (score 1):

From the above two answers you know how to retrieve the files from the document directory.

and Now you want how to open a file when a user tap on te cell.

you just have to use the UITableView delegate function i.e

```
       -(void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
        {
               //do all your file opening logic here.
               //your file data is stored in the NSArray myFileData(refer the previous answer posted above)
              //and suppose you want to fetch the data which is in the file, is of type NSURL, means the file data is just a URL link.
        //just declare a NSURL in your .h(say myURL) (synthesize it etc)


        myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[myFileData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
         }
```

now your myURL is having the link which is stored in the file and then you can use that url in your webView.

Comment: I understand that but how do I get a certain file to open when a certain row is tapped? Can you give a small example please?